# How to show different content in the sidebar on a static home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a Wordpress noob and trying to figure out the best way to show different content in the side bar only on home page. I have set the front page to be static and right now it shows the usual widgets from the blog posts page.  I just need to show  some custom content in the sidebar only on the home page. So far I have found solutions to install plugins, multiple sidebars etc. I was thinking more along the lines of having some conditions to show different content within the existing sidebar. Can someone please advise how can I achieve this task?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the theme on your home page using a different template? You could modify what sidebar is shown after you register a new sidebar in the functions.

Comment: I'm using undestrap: https://wordpress.org/themes/understrap/ . Yes I am using a different template for home page but do I really need to have a different sidebar for this. Wouldn't it be better to have a condition at widgets level ?

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood the question I suppose. Try `if(is_front_page() )`

Comment: You can read more about it at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way is to edit `sidebar.php` file and find where you want to add sidebar (for example at the top) and check if `is_front_page()` then use a function to check if `is_active_sidebar('frontpage_sidebar')` and else the rest of global widgets.
after that you should register a sidebar named `frontpage_sidebar`.

**functions.php**

```
$args = array(
'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
'id'            => 'frontpage_sidebar',    // ID should be LOWERCASE  ! ! !
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget'  => '</li>',
'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title'   => '</h2>' );
register_sidebar($args);
```

**sidebar.php**

```
if(is_front_page()){
    if(is_active_sidebar('frontpage_sidebar')){
        dynamic_sidebar('frontpage_sidebar');
    }else{
       echo 'please set a sidebar for your frontpage';
    }
}else{
   if(is_active_sidebar('sidebar')){
       dynamic_sidebar('sidebar');
   }else{
       echo 'please set default widgets for whole pages';
   }
}
```

*i didn't check this code, so please check and let me know if it works.*